# WPF and dynamically styled textblock (bold/italic)

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I know that in WPF you can do something like:

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run Text="This is normal text" />
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="This is bolded text" />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

This will allow text with normal weight font and bold font.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a string that can be bolded in places (some kind of specifier). I have tried a Converter that will check if the text has  **and**  around parts
of the text and will style appropriately.  I have never found a working version of a converter that
will properly put a bold or italicized string into a textblock dynamically into xaml.

Please give me some hint on this if possible.
Thanks.

I have tried various converters that attempt to do this without result.

Comment: You need a Binding Converter that returns a collection of Inlines, and either an attached property or a dependency property in a TextBlock subclass that modifies the TextBlock.Inlines collection, which is not bindable.